# How to combine values ​of only adjacent lists?

Tags: python

```
wells = [
    [
        [0, 4, 'earth'],
        [4, 8, 'suglinok'],
        [8, 20, 'gravel'],
    ],
    [
        [0, 4, 'earth'],
        [4, 8, 'suglinok'],
        [8, 20, 'sand'],
    ],
    [
        [0, 4, 'earth'],
        [4, 16, 'suglinok'],
        [16, 24, 'gravel'],
    ]
]
points_by_description = {}

for well in wells:
    for point in well:
        start, end, description = point

        if description in points_by_description:
            points_by_description[description].extend([start, end])
        else:
            points_by_description[description] = [start, end]

for description, points in points_by_description.items():
    for i in range(0, len(points), 2):
        print([points[i], points[i + 1]], end=" ")
    print()
```

My script connects the beginnings and ends of lists with the same descriptions.
Output looks like this:

```
[0, 4] [0, 4] [0, 4] 
[4, 8] [4, 8] [4, 16] 
[8, 20] [16, 24] 
[8, 20]
```

I need to change the code so that connections are only looked for in adjacent lists.
The output should look like this:

```
[0, 4] [0, 4] [0, 4] 
[4, 8] [4, 8] [4, 16] 
[8, 20]
[8, 20]
[16, 24]
```

no idea how to do this

Comment: Why the gravel is not combined?  [8, 20], [16, 24]

Comment: @MisterCat, This is the essence of the task. they are not connected because they are not in adjacent lists.

Comment: Can you clarify a little bit by "adjacent list" here

Comment: use `defaultdict(list)`

Comment: @MisterCat, I mean that the lists must be consecutive so that their lists with the same description can be connected. In this case, the first 'gravel' is in wells[0], and the second is in wells[2]. If the second gravel was in the wells[1], then we could connect them. This is what I call adjacent lists

Comment: @rioV8, can you send me full code with this remark? i dont understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep track if you have seen the description in a well

```py
from collections import defaultdict

points_by_description = defaultdict(list)
descriptionInWell = defaultdict(set)

for wellIdx,well in enumerate(wells):
    for start, end, description in well:
        descriptionInWell[description].add(wellIdx)
        if not(wellIdx-1 in descriptionInWell[description]):
            points_by_description[description].append([])
        points_by_description[description][-1].extend([start, end])

for description, pointLists in points_by_description.items():
    for points in pointLists:
        for i in range(0, len(points), 2):
            print([points[i], points[i + 1]], end=" ")
        print()
```

Answer (score 0):

The exact expected output is unclear, but assuming you want a dictionary with the description as key and a list of list as value with the consecutive values with the same description grouped in a sublist, you could use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain), [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby, chain

out = {}
for k, g in groupby(chain.from_iterable(zip(*wells)), key=lambda x: x[-1]):
    out.setdefault(k, []).append([x for l in g for x in l[:-1]])
```

Output:

```
{'earth': [[0, 4, 0, 4, 0, 4]],
 'suglinok': [[4, 8, 4, 8, 4, 16]],
 'gravel': [[8, 20], [16, 24]],
 'sand': [[8, 20]]}
```

Comment: The output should look like this:

[0, 4] [0, 4] [0, 4] 
[4, 8] [4, 8] [4, 16] 
[8, 20]
[8, 20]
[16, 24]. Check me question again pls

Comment: @TommyVercetti please update the question with the exact output in a reproducible format.

Comment: @TommyVercetti I don't see how the accepted answer is different, this gives the same dictionary…